# Run build only if there are changes in src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, gruntjs, protractor

**The story:**

We have a team of testers working on automating end-to-end tests using protractor for our internal AngularJS application. Here is the task they usually run for "local" testing:

```
grunt.registerTask('e2e:local', [
    'build:prod',
    'connect:test',
    'protractor:local'
]);
```

It runs the "build" task, starts a webserver and runs the e2e tests against the local build.

The `build:prod` task itself is defined as:

```
grunt.registerTask(
    'build:prod', [
        'clean',
        'copy:all',
        'copy:assets',
        'wiredep',
        'ngtemplates',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'autoprefixer',
        'uglify',
        'cssmin',
        'copy:cssfix',
        'usemin',
        'copy:html',
        'bowercopy',
        'template:setProdVersion'
    ]
);
```

Here we have a lot of subtasks (it definitely could be improved, but this is how it looks now).

**The problem:**

Currently, it takes about 25 seconds for the build to complete. And, every time a person is running end-to-end tests, the build task is executed.

**The question:**

How can I run the `build:prod` task only if there are changes in `src` directory?

---

Note that the requirement here is to *make it transparent* for the testers who run the tests. I don't want them to remember when they need to perform a build and when not.

In other words, the process should be automated. The goal is to automatically detect if build is needed or not.

Note that ideally I would like to leave the build task as is, so that if it is invoked directly via `grunt build:prod` it would rebuild regardless of the datestamp of the previous build.

---

Thoughts and tries:

- there is the closely related [`grunt-newer` package](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer), but, since we have a rather complicated build, having a `clean` task at the beginning, I'm not sure how to apply it in my case
- what I was also thinking about is to, inside the `e2e:local` task, manually check the timestamps of the files inside `dist` and `src` and, based on that, decide if `build:prod` is needed to be invoked. I think this is what `grunt-newer` is doing internally
- we started to use [`jit-grunt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jit-grunt) that helped to improve the performance

Comment: The man page (http://grunt-tasks.com/grunt-newer/) for `grunt-newer` seems to support your second bullet, create a task that checks dates of `src` files and fire if they have changed (not sure why you'd check `dist`, isn't that the result of the build?)

Comment: @KevinDTimm yeah, the ideas that `grunt-newer` are very close to what I'm asking about. The second bullet/thought was about comparing the timestamps inside the `dist`, which is yes, the result of build, and timestamps inside the `src`. And if inside the `src` files are newer, then run the build. May be this is not how I should do it and better compare the `src` file stamps between current and previous runs..thanks.

Comment: What I could suggest is to set an alias in your ~/.cshrc to run the build commands only if a diff command returns true.

Comment: Why the `clean` task at the very start of the build??

Comment: @Louis this is sort of "legacy" build task we've inherited. "clean" cleans up build and dist directories. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Here's an idea if you use git:

How about using something like [grunt-gitinfo](https://github.com/damkraw/grunt-gitinfo) and using the last commit in HEAD as a base?

The idea is:

- You create a new grunt task that checks for latest commit hash
- You'd save this commit hash in a file that's added to `gitignore` (and is NOT in the `clean` folder, typically can be in root of repo)
- Before saving to file, it'd check the value already in it (standard node `fs` module can do the read/write easily)
- If the hash doesn't match, run `build:prod` task then save new commit hash
- The testers build would depend on your new task instead of `build:prod` directly

#### Another option (still using git):

You can use something like [grunt-githooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks) and create a git hook that runs after pull and calls the git `build:prod`, then you can remove it from the dependencies of the grunt task that testers run.

You might have another code to check for githook and install it if required though, which can be a one-time extra step for testers, or maybe baked into the grunt task they call.

Comment: That's quite an interesting idea in general! Good out-of-the-box thinking. Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised noone has mentioned [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) yet (it's in the [gruntjs.com](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) example file and I thought it was pretty commonly known!). From github: "Run predefined tasks whenever watched file patterns are added, changed or deleted." - heres a sample grunt file that would run your tasks any time any .js files are modified in src/ or in test/, or if the Gruntfile is modified.

```
var filesToWatch = ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'];
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        files: filesToWatch,
        tasks: ['build:prod',
                'connect:test',
                'protractor:local']
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```

You have your developers open a terminal and run `grunt watch` before they start modifying files, and every time those files are modified the tasks will automatically be run (no more going back to the terminal to run `grunt build:prod` every time).

It's an excellent package and I suggest you check it out. -- [github](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) -- [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-watch)

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
```

Comment: "I don't want them to remember when they need to perform a build and when not. In other words, the process should be automated. The goal is to automatically detect if build is needed or not." - This not only detects when the build is needed (by watching the files in `src/`), but automatically compiles the build whenever it detects the build is needed. This both automates the process removing the need for them to know when to build, and builds when building is needed.

Comment: Yes, the "watch" probably is the easiest option. It would still require testers to remember running the task and have it active, but it definitely helps to make it transparent. Now we can remove the build task call from the e2e task. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer your are looking for with `grunt`, but this will be easy with `gulp`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');

var sourceChanged = fs.statSync('build/directory').mtime > fs.statSync('source/directory').mtime;

gulp.task('build:prod', function() {
  if (!sourceChanged) {
    return false;
  } 
  return gulp.src('./src/*.js')
    .pipe(.... build ....)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we've done some Git HEAD sha work for our build. We use it to determine which version is currently deployed to our production environment - but I'm quite certain you could rework it to return a boolean and trigger the build if truthy.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
function getHeadSha() {
  var curr, match, next = 'HEAD';
  var repoDir = process.env.GIT_REPO_DIR || path.join(__dirname, '..');
  try {
    do {
      curr  = grunt.file.read(path.join(repoDir, '.git', next)).trim();
      match = curr.match(/^ref: (.+)$/);
      next  = match && match[1];
    } while (next);
  } catch(ex) {
    curr = 'not-found';
  }

  return curr;
}

grunt.initConfig({
  replace: {
    applicationVersion: {
      src:  '<%= config.dist %>/index.html',
      overwrite: true,
      replacements: [{
        from: '{{APPLICATION_VERSION}}',
        to:   getHeadSha
      }]
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('build', {
  'replace:applicationVersion',
  /** other tasks **/
});

grunt.registerTask('e2e:local', {
  'check_if_we_should_build',
  /** other tasks **/
});
```

---

**index.html**

```
<html data-version="{{APPLICATION_VERSION}}">
  <!-- -->
</html>
```

---

There's also the [git-info](https://github.com/damkraw/grunt-gitinfo) package which would simplify this whole process, we're looking at switching over to that ourselves.

*edit;* I just noticed @meligy already pointed you in the direction of git-info. credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if its helpful or not but same things we have done it in our project using [GULP framework](http://gulpjs.com/). We have written a watcher in the gulp that continuously check for the source change and run a quick function to build the project. Its a Protractor Test case.

```
gulp.task('dome', function () {


    gulp.src(["maintest.js"])
        .pipe(notify("Change Found , Executing Scripts."))
        .pipe(protractor({

            configFile: "conf.js",
            args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000']


        })).on('error', function (e) {
        throw e
    });
})


gulp.task('default', function () {


    gulp.watch('./webpages/*.js', ['dome']);
    gulp.watch('maintest.js', ['dome']);
    gulp.watch('conf.js', ['dome']);
});
```

[Link to repo.](https://github.com/PramodDutta/Protractr_WithPOM_GULP/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience in protractor, but conceptually I think this could work.

What I could suggest is to set an alias in your ~/.cshrc to run the build commands only if a `diff` command returns true.

```
#./cshrc

alias build_on_diff 'diff -r branch_dir_1 branch_dir_2\
if ( $status == 1 ) then\
build:prod\
endif'
```

Just replace the `diff` command with whatever git uses, and it should work provided it returns a 1 status for differences detected. We apply a similar method at my workplace to avoid rebuilding files that haven't changed.